# How to put a conditional inside another conditional | Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can I add another conditional to the following conditional statement:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

Me.myTime = Now()
Me.dayText = Now()

    If TimeValue(Now()) = #3:00:00 PM# Then
        Call Button1_Click
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
End Sub
```

The `Form_Timer()` triggers the button `Button1` to click when the time is 3:00 pm in the textbox myTime.

But I also have a textbox called `dayText` that displays the current Day of the week.

I would like `Button1` to be triggered only if the day is not Saturday or Sunday and the time is 3:00 pm.

**So I am looking to do something like this:**

```
If Me.dayText = #Saturday# or #Sunday# Then

    If TimeValue(Now()) = #3:00:00 PM# Then
    Call Button1_Click
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End If

End If
```

**The 2 textboxes look like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like Button1 to be triggered only if the day is not Saturday
>   or Sunday and the time is 3:00 pm.

That code can be written like this:

```vb
If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) < 6 Then
    ' Weekend day.
    If DateDiff("s", Time, #3:00:00 PM#) = 0 Then
        Call Button1_Click
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding what `Weekday(Date, vbMonday) < 6` means in your code. Can you please explain?

Comment: `Weekday` returns the date's _day of the week_. The second argument determines the first day of the week.

Comment: But the script should not run on Saturdays or Sunday’s, I think my wording was big confusing, the second conditional should only execute if the day is Monday - Friday

Comment: Yes. And that's what is will.

Comment: Ok just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 0):

If your textbox `dayText` is date formatted (means have date value) then you can use following.

```
If Format(Me.dayText, "dddd") = "Saturday" Or Format(Me.dayText, "dddd") = "Sunday" Then
    If TimeValue(Now()) = #3:00:00 PM# Then
        Call Button1_Click
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
End If
```

Comment: That will fail in any non-English environment.

Comment: The expression `TimeValue(Now()) = #3:00:00 PM#` relies on the timer ticking at the *exact* moment that `Now()` equals `15:00:00` - better to test whether `Now()` or `Time()` is within a given tolerance (say, a second or two) within `15:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it is not necessary to use a nested conditional statement in this particular scenario, as the *else* branch is the same regardless of whether either test expression is not validated.

As such, an `and` operator between the two test expressions should suffice, e.g.:

```
If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) < 6 And Abs(DateDiff("s", Time, #3:00:00 PM#)) < 3 Then
    Call Button1_Click
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End If
```

The above uses a tolerance of 3 seconds either side of `15:00:00` - you should adjust this tolerance depending on the frequency of the tick of your timer.